# Discord bot not working. Cannot find a solution

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a bot for Discord from a video I've found in YouTube. When done in the video, it seems to work just fine, but idk what could be possibly wrong. It's a Massive DMs Bot, btw

dmass.py

```
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord import game
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import platform
import colorsys
import random
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '+', case_insensitive=True)
Client = discord.client
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as '+client.user.name+' (ID:'+client.user.id+') | Connected to '+str(len(client.servers))+' servers | Connected to '+str(len(set(client.get_all_members())))+' users')
    print('--------')
    print('--------')
    print('CREATED AND HOSTED BY SUBHANKAR DAS')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)     
async def userinfo(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    r, g, b = tuple(int(x * 255) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(random.random(), 1, 1))
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info".format(user.name), description="Here's what I could find.", color = discord.Color((r << 16) + (g << 8) + b))
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=user.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Highest role", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=user.joined_at)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    await client.say(embed=embed)
    
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def send(ctx, *, content: str):
        for member in ctx.message.server.members:
            try:
                await client.send_message(member, content)
                await client.say("DM Sent To : {} :white_check_mark:  ".format(member))
            except:
                print("can't")
                await client.say("DM can't Sent To : {} :x: ".format(member))


client.run("YOUR BOT'S TOKEN HERE")
```

Procfile

`worker: python dmass.py`

Requirements.txt

```
discord.py==0.16.12
asyncio
```

Comment: Btw, I'm hosting it in Heroku

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, ivy. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please write down the exact error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the problem in here. Did you follow step by step that tutorial?
Check if everything is okay.
By the way, did you put your bot's token in the last line correctly? Maybe that's causing the problem.
Anyway, I can't see the point of this question exactly, what is not working, it can't start up or it can't send DM's?